# OOB Language ISO Code?

Tags: apex, language

Is there any standard functionality in apex that gives me the ISO code of a string(english - en).
I am looking for better approach to handle this.

One of the idea was to store languages and iso codes in custom settings and get it from there, but if there are any other better ways that i should try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this mapping is not standard. Custom Settings are indeed the most efficient way to go. You want a `List Custom Setting` where the `Name` corresponds to the language name. Add a custom field called `ISO Code` and populate it with the values you want.